# How can I automate the ordering of a Stacked Bar plot in Python using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, math, ggplot2

I am currently creating a stacked bar plot using a dataframe and I'd like to change the ordering of the bars in order of magnitude. I have a dataframe as following:

```
df = ( 
   H  C  O
A  2  1  3
B  1  2  1
C  3  1  1
D  1  2  3
E  1  3  1)

df.plot.bar(stacked = True).legend(loc='upper center', ncol=3)
```

The problem I am coming into is that the first column has priority in ordering. I would like an output that stacks bars in increasing value found in each column.

I am not opposed to sending each row into a new list, or dataframe, or indices and plotting them separately and then concatanting, but I am very new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colors = pd.Series({
    'H':'C0',
    'C':'C1',
    'O':'C2'
})

for i,r in df.iterrows():
    row = r.sort_values().cumsum()[::-1]
    ax.bar([i]*len(row), row, color=row.index.map(colors))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the blue bar at the bottom is being taken from the 'H' column in every single case. For cases where values of C or O are higher, I would like that column to be placed first.

Comment: Ah **first column has priority in ordering** is misleading. That's will be a little tricky, but can be done with a `for` loop.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on that? Would I need to create new lists for each column or can I send a 'for' loop inside the plot?

Comment: Exactly like that, except the largest block should begin at the bottom

Comment: Add `ascending=False` to `sort_values`, i.e. `sort_values(ascending=False)`

Comment: This is it! Beautiful!